# Hint for a version of Kummer's Lemma

Tags: commutative-algebra

I am having some troubles in proving the following:

Let $R$ be a local ring, and $\mathfrak{m}$ its maximal ideal, $k=R/\mathfrak{m}$. If $f\in R[X]$ is monic and irreducible and $\bar{f}=\prod_{i=1}^r \bar{g}_i^{e_i}$ is a decomposition of $f+\mathfrak{m}$ in $k[X]$ into monic and pairwise coprime irreducible factors $\bar{g}_i\in k[X]$. Then if we pick $g_i\in R[X]$ lifting $\bar{g}_i$, we find that $\{\mathfrak{m}_1,\dots,\mathfrak{m}_r\}$ is the set of maximal ideals of $R[X]/(f)$, where $\mathfrak{m}_i=(\mathfrak{m},g_i)$.

I feel that Nakayama's Lemma can help here, but I don't know where to start. Any hint would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you realize that any maximal ideal of $R[X]/(f)$ contains $\mathfrak{m}$, since $f$ is monic?

Comment: A proof of that fact may be really helpful. I don't know how to use the fact that $f$ is monic to prove that.

Comment: Use division algorithm to show that $R[X]/(f)$ is a finitely generated module over $R$ and thus so is $R[X]/(f)$ modulo any maximal ideal. This is of course non-zero, but for any non-zero finitely generated $R$-module $N$, $N/\mathfrak{m}N\neq 0$ by Nakayama's lemma.

Comment: @Mohan I did't understand your solution. How can I use Nakayama's lemma?